# Regex matching abc:abc

Tags: regex

I want to capture:

```
sometext
sometext:description
```

- If input is in the form of `sometext:description` I want to capture both
  `sometext` and `description` (I can do that using `([a-z]+):([a-z]+)`)
- If input is in the form of `sometext` I want to capture only `sometext` (I can do that using `([a-z]+)`)

How can I combine the two expressions together? That if and only if the input is of the form `a:b` I'll capture both, else just `a`

I've tried:

```
((([a-z]+):([a-z]+)) | ([a-z]+))
```

But it won't capture `'abcde'`

Comment: Both the colon and the description are optional. They need `(...)?` around them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the second pattern inside a non-capturing group and make it as optional.

```
([a-z]+)(?::([a-z]+))?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rG1mG8/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
 ^(\w+)(?:\:(\w+))?$
```

It will match both strings. See [example](https://regex101.com/r/eR1dQ0/3).

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-z]+):([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)
```

Your regex is working for me.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/62

> ((([a-z]+):([a-z]+)) | ([a-z]+))

```
                 ^^^^
```

These spaces are causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks didn't notice the spaces.However, In `sometext:description` it captures `sometext:description` as well as `sometext` and `description`, I only need the latter two (not me who downvoted btw)